# MODX как создавать шаблоны более эффективно?

Tags: modx

Доброго времени суток, друзья. 
Я долгое время работаю с Wordpress, но в последнее время захотел попробовать что-то новое, остановился пока что на MODX. Мне все понятно в этой системе, но вот непонятно одно - почему шаблоны хранятся в БД о_0 Как-то это не серьезно что ли...

Друзья, подскажите, есть ли возможность создавать шаблоны в файлах, папках, как в других CMS? Я работаю в PhpStorm, но шаблоны под MODX нужно создавать только из админки сайта, если правильно понял? Насколько такой подход эффективный судить не мне, но не вериться, что в столь популярном движке нет возможности создавать шаблоны более эффективно, удобно. Помогите разобраться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прекрасно можно хранить и в файлах.
Структуру проекта можете создать абсолютно любую. Например, при создании шаблона в админке указать галочку **"Статичный"**, затем выбираете файл в котором хранится шаблон. Всё, теперь можно работать с файлом напрямую, без входа в админку.

Тоже самое можно применить к чанкам и сниппетам.

Comment: Попробовал, работает! Здорово, спасибо большое!